# PHP update work on PHP but didnt update on mysql database

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have been working on uploading picture to a folder and saving the file name and some meta info to a MySQL database. I got everything working on PHP but nothing changes on my database. I don't know what is wrong.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "poster";
$uploadOk = "0";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['btn-upload'])) {   
    $owner = $_POST['userid']; 
    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type']; 
    $folder = "profile/";

    if (!empty ($owner)) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
       echo "Are you sure you are not in the wrong place?";

       $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    // new file size in KB
    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    // make file name in lower case
    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    if ($file_type != 'jpg' ) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "Only jpg file type allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if ($file_size > '5000') {
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "Your image file must be less than 5Mb";
    $uploadOK = 0;
}

if (move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file) && $uploadOk == 1) {
    $sql = "UPDATE post SET `file`='$final_file', `type` = '$file_type' WHERE `userid`='$owner'";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Html Result

```
Record updated successfully
```

Database

```
|userid   | file|type|
| 1       | foo | foo|
```

It said record updated successfully but nothing gets updated in my database. What did I do wrong here?

p.s.
Yes I do know that I should be using PDO by now, but I just need to finish this as my first PHP project.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure you want to do an update, and not an insert if this is a new row of data?

Comment: Yes I want to update. Its for user profile picture.

Comment: note, `file` is a reserved word in mysql:   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html.  You might want to change your key for that one, or use backticks around it in your query

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: also `type`.   See my answer below.

Comment: update with your question with the HTML form. No way for us to tell whether or not it's correct. Plus, you should be using `affected_rows()` in order to check if the update was truly successful. Update your question also to show us the column's lengths and types.

Comment: @nomistic "file" is a keyword and not a reserved word same for "type" (look at the letters R next to reserved words). Something else is causing their code to fail, otherwise they would be getting syntax errors; I guess the OP would have told us that by now and in their question.

Comment: So, the file does get successfully uploaded, correct? Just the db doesn't get updated? @Zalo

Comment: @Fred-ii- I stand corrected.  I have modified my answer;  I'm thinking this may have something to do with the jumping between styles

Comment: @nomistic OP isn't telling us the whole story. If they're trying to update the same id (one we don't know if it is correct in their HTML form and where it's being populated as, a POST or a GET), that is unknownst to us. It's probably failing silently too. The columns' types and lengths, something I've asked the OP to let us know. They should also be doing a var_dump to show us what's being passed in there (or not). It's just a big mystery at this point.

Comment: I am moving on and have closed this tab. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are jumping between procedural style and object oriented style with your queries;  this may be part of your problem.

Try changing your connection to this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Incidentally, since you mention it, you don't necessarily have to use PDO for prepared statements.  As you like mysqli, you can do it with these.  You are already halfway there.  After you've done the above, just do this:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE post SET `file`= ?, `type` = ? WHERE userid= ? ");
$sql->bind_param("ssi", $file, $file_type, $owner);
$sql->execute();
$sql->close();
```

The `ssi` above just refers to "string string integer" (or whatever file types you are using, assuming the first two are varchars, and the third is an INT).  Basically you are setting the parameters for each file to go into your query;  you don't need to remember whether to quote or not quote the variable depending on type, as you've defined it in the `bind_param()` below.

It's fairly self-explanatory, and not hard to learn.  Like I said, you are halfway there.

Comment: You may very well be right about their method, from procedural to object oriented. Let's see what the OP has to say, and if they've read the new comments or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have just made a error in either you database design or the way you record the new upload.

```
UPDATE post SET `file`='$final_file', `type` = '$file_type' WHERE `userid`='$owner'";
```

This will amend an already created row. So you will only ever have one row per user, and therefore when the user uploads a second file it will over write the previous data.

Assuming the `userid` column is not defines as `auto increment` you should in fact be creating a new row for each file a user uploads with an INSERT query rather than an UPDATE like so

```
INSERT INTO post (userid,file,type)      
          VALUES ('$owner', '$final_file', '$file_type')
```

Now you will get a new row for this user for each file they upload.